# How to use `should_panic` in tokio test?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

When running a normal test we can use `#[should_panic]` macro to test fail cases.
What is the corresponding alternative for `#[tokio::test]`

Answer (score 2):

Just use both:

```rust
#[tokio::test]
#[should_panic]
async fn t1() {
    panic!("Nice panic!");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=85b029dc4121264d7711e5c6ee0c30a5)